# Enable Lightning Experience in Customer Community Profile

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, customer-community

My Customer Community uses Salesforce Tabs +Visualforce as a Template.I don't see an option to enable **Lightning Experience User** in Customer Community Profile.

[image]

http://www.salesforce.com/company/news-press/press-releases/2016/06/160623.jsp
http://www.algoworks.com/blog/lightning-customer-community/

Comment: I've seen it in the Napili template now, but I'm not sure about adding it to the tabs + VF communities setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Winter 17 Salesforce doesn't support lightning experience in Communities.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_gaps_limitations_other_products.htm&type=0&language=en_US

[image]